# Почему слово "брюки" не бывает в единственном числе?

Tags: морфология

Есть такие слова, которые в единственном числе не употребляются: ножницы, штаны, брюки и т.д. А вот интересно, почему? Ножницы - я еще могу понять: они состоят из двух частей. А почему брюки? Да, у них две штанины, но и у свитера два рукава, а туфель так вообще две отдельные штуки. Но почему-то именно брюки и штаны бывают исключительно во множественном числе? С чем это связано?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раньше брюки состояли из двух отдельных частей, отсюда множественное число:

Брюки
(голл. broek) - верхняя поясная одежда; состоит из двух передних и двух задних половинок, соединенных боковыми и шаговыми швами и средним швом. Верх Б. обычно оформляется поясом. Вплоть до XVIII в. ***брюки состояли из двух частей, порознь надевавшихся на ноги*** и скреплявшихся на поясе шнурком. [Энциклопедия моды и одежды](http://enc-dic.com/enc_fashion/Brjuki-2031.html)

А ещё русском языке есть слово ШТАНЫ, по аналогии с ним, вероятно,  стали употреблять слово брюки.

В единственном числе:

БРЮЧИНА - часть брюк, покрывающая одну ногу; штанина. Толковый словарь Ефремовой. .

Answer (score 3):

Надо думать, что из двух частей состояли не только брюки, но и все их предшественники:  портки - от др.-рус. пъртъ  - одежда, штаны - начало 17 века, шаровары -  в словаре с 18 века, но реально раньше,  панталоны - первая треть 19 века. Все они употребляются в форме множественного числа.

Итак, 20-ы е годы 19 века. Вспомним "Евгения Онегина": Но панталоны, фрак, жилет, Всех этих слов на русском нет". До панталон русское военное дворянство носило длинные штаны/шаровары, заправленные в сапоги. Хотя придворной одеждой ещё считались короткие штаны, чулки и башмаки, но и военная форма никого не шокировала, в штанах можно было пойти на бал и во дворец.

Но вот во времена Пушкина франты стали носить белые панталоны навыпуск, что представлялось чудовищным неприличием - простонародными портками в качестве светской одежды. Один такой франт в панталонах явился на московский великосветский вечер, но вызвал гнев хозяйки: "Не у меня только, не у меня! Ко мне, слава Богу, никто еще в портках не входит!" Но вот уже и в письмах Вяземского (1821 год) мы  читаем: "Я хлопочу о портках".

С брюками, которые заменили панталоны,  были те же проблемы. Сначала широкие брюки считались матросскими штанами, и одевший их щеголь вполне мог услышать следующее: Тебя пригласили на бал танцевать, а не на мачту лазить; а ты вздумал нарядиться матросом".
(Из книги Ю. Лотмана).

ЕЩЁ О ШТАНАХ (КАКИМИ ОНИ БЫЛИ)

1)Славянские штаны  http://intuitsia.com/slavyanskaya-odezhda/

Славянские штаны делались не слишком широкими: на сохранившихся изображениях они обрисовывают ногу. Кроили их из прямых полотнищ, а между штанинами ("в шагу") вставляли ластовицу - для удобства ходьбы: если пренебречь этой деталью, пришлось бы семенить, а не шагать. Штаны делались примерно по щиколотку длиной и на голени заправлялись в онучи.
Разреза штаны не имели, а на бёдрах держались с помощью шнурка.

2)Портки и штаны. Вообразим невыразимое? http://shkolazhizni.ru/archive/0/n-41407/

Столь знакомое нам слово «брюки» появилось не так давно и пришло из нидерландского языка. До этого пользовались словом «штаны» (по основной версии – слово турецкого происхождения), а еще раньше – словом «порты», или «портки». А еще в русском литературном языке 19 века бытовало очень стыдливое слово для мужской одежды – «невыразимое» (или «невыразимые»). Невыразимое – и все тут. Сразу всем читателям понятно. Зафиксировано и в литературе: «Его бухарский халат разъехался спереди, и обнаружились препротивные нижние невыразимые из замшевой кожи» (И. Тургенев. Повесть «Несчастная»). Или у Тургенева же: «Выхожу – и вижу – за калиткой – человека дурно одетого с разодранными невыразимыми, а перед калиткой Пэгаз в позе победителя» (очерк «Пэгаз»).

Answer (score 3):

В голландском брюки (broek) - вполне себе единственного. Точно также заимствовано в немецком и т.д.  
Объяснение, что раньше состояли из двух половин, не очень смотрится. Оно, конечно, так, но, получается, что только на русской почве. 
На самом деле здесь именно что аналогия. В русском языке все слова, обозначающие предметы нижней одежды, конструктивно имеющие правую и левую часть - для каждой из ног - имеют названия, грамматически соответствующие множественному числу: портки (порты - "родоначальник" такой одежды на Руси), трусы, рейтузы, кальсоны, колготки и т.д. Разумеется, большинство из них не из каких *самостоятельных* частей никогда не состояло. Но русским менталитетом воспринимается, видимо с незапамятных времен, как нечто двойное. 
К сожалению, мне не удалось проследить языковую историю русских портков до времен достаточно древних. Но, думаю, тогдашние русские штаны носили название, представляющее собой число двойственное. Как и многое из того, что относится к человеческому (и не только) телу и имеет правую и левую части - рога, глаза.